# configuring java agents in tomcat for multiple war files separately

Tags: java, tomcat, javaagents

I need to configure the java agents in tomcat.
Basically in `catalina.sh` file `JAVA_OPT=-javaagent:/agentPath/`.
But there are three apps in the webapp folder,
like app1.war, app2.war, app3.war. I need to configure java agents separately for each war file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A Java Agent is attached to a running JVM, not a webapp, so you would need to have three running instances of Tomcat in that case.